# Gson: Format double values to 4 decimal places

Tags: java, json, gson

How can I go about making Gson format double values round (or truncate) to 4 decimal places?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. Can use a type adapter:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, (JsonSerializer<Double>) (src, typeOfSrc, context) -> {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
    return new JsonPrimitive(Double.parseDouble(df.format(src)));
});
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Comment: The following snipet fails: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
Double.parseDouble(df.format(Double.valueOf(0.0123457d)));` with `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,0124".`

Comment: Because you're not in a 'decimal period' part of the world, you have to add `df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(US_FORMATTER_SYMBOLS);`

Comment: Actually I think this behaves exactly the same as `Math.rint(src * 10000) / 10000` except in cases where the value is close to the absolute maximum double value. In both cases I think it still can render the double with a long tail of ±1ulp if you're unlucky.

Answer (score 4):

If you are attempting this in **Kotlin** Aman's answer will still work but you must use a type token rather than Double.class(or Double::class.java):

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(object: TypeToken<Double>() {}.type, ...
```